# How configure multiple IP Failover on the same VM?

Tags: networking, ip, routing, virtual-machines

I'm trying to configure multiple IP Failover on the same VM behing Proxmox VE.

I've got these IP : IP1, IP2 and IP3. IP1 is the main one. I've configured in Proxmox these IP in veth with theses infos :

- Name : eth0, Mac : Virtual_Mac_Ip1
- Name : eth1, Mac : Virtual_Mac_Ip2
- Name : eth2, Mac : Virtual_Mac_Ip3

And I've modify my /etc/network/interfaces file in my VM with this :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address IP_1
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast IP_1
    post-up route add MAIN_IP dev eth0
    post-up route add default gw MAIN_IP
    post-down route del MAIN_IP dev eth0
    post-down route del default gw MAIN_IP


auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address IP_2
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast IP_2
    post-up route add MAIN_IP dev eth1
    post-up route add default gw MAIN_IP
    post-down route del MAIN_IP dev eth1
    post-down route del default gw MAIN_IP

auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address IP_3
    netmask 255.255.255.255
    broadcast IP_3
    post-up route add MAIN_IP dev eth2
    post-up route add default gw MAIN_IP
    post-down route del MAIN_IP dev eth2
    post-down route del default gw MAIN_IP
```

With this configuration, I can't ping none of my IP. If a configure in /etc/network/interfaces only one IP (eth0, eth1 or eth2), this one works !

What is wrong with that ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve by this configuration? How three interfaces to the same network on the same host could improve availability at all? Also, please make setup more concrete, for example, how the network configured on the other side (where "MAIN_IP" is set).

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the netmask from all 255.255.255.255 to your actual subnet number, so if you're using a 24bit schema, change it to 255.255.255.0 only.

Hope this works.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've just tried and it doesn't work.